# AR model with white noise model, DGP is T(5), why no misspecification?

Tags: misspecification

Let $x_t$ =ϕ$x_{t−1}$+$ε _t$ be the model with errors being white noise.  ​ If DGP  is $X_t$=$e_t$ which is T(5) distributed. Why no misspecification?

Comment: Why do you think there *is* a misspecification?

Comment: or, to ask the opposite question: why do you think there is no misspecification ? jbowman: I might not be understanding the question but it seems to me like there is misspecification ?

Comment: There is no misspecification and I dont understand why.  I want to see a more rigorous argumentation than following: Model is misspecified if the true DGP is not contained in the model. And I kind of see how you can capture T distribution with this model but I am not convinced